UK Visit visa after leaving without notifying
Let me summaerize my situation:

UK student visa: 2011
Visa canceled (deception of language certificate in the UK, after extending my visa) and ordered to leave in 60 days: end of 2013.
Appealed against the decision and waited for the court decision.
No work, no study, so I left the UK by car to the EU without notifying: end of 2014 (no overstay, case was in court).
In the EU I applied for asylum and started studies (a company sponsored): early 2015.

After completing my studies (3 years), I was offered a job and received a residence permit as a skilled worker. Now I have a good job and a permanent residence permit (soon citizenship).
Out of interest, I want to visit the UK again. Just to see people I know and places again and remember those days.
What could have changed since? Do I have any chance of getting a UK visit visa? What should/could I do?

I am not an expert here but I imagine it might be different if you become an EU citizen.

Using deception normally results in a 10 year entry ban, which would still be in effect if you left end of 2014. If I were you I’d wait until you get your EU citizenship before you attempt to visit the UK. At that point depending on your risk appetite you can choose between applying for a visa (given your immigration history) or seeking permission to enter at the border.
